# Material Component is not able to change color

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-ui

please I try to resolve this problem for two days, but unsuccessfull

I have a problem with new material design components

I used style Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox

I try get this result.. (without change theme colors) only xml or code

[image]

my actual widget.. :(

[image]

my Theme

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge
```

xml code of component

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/core_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:layout_weight="9">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:hint="Trip name"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

style

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
</style>

<style name="HintText" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2">
    <item name="android:textColor">?secondaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

I tried everything from internet, but i dont know where is a problem. thanks for any help

In gradle i have all latest versions of libs and build version

If zou want additional info write.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure it responds to your changes? The colors are way off, also you need to add more radius on the corners

Comment: yes, when not use style HintText then "trip titpe" is with white color
please have you some xmls where can change color scheme from xml? thanks

Comment: You can override the theme, but you must find what colors and styles it is using.

Comment: i have colors in theme but this inputs its special in theme. its not able to change via xml or programmatically? only colors from theme? i have custom theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem can resolve with this lines in custom theme

```
   <item name="colorPrimary">?secondary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?secondaryVariant</item>
   <item name="colorOnPrimary">?onSecondaryH</item>
   <item name="colorSecondary">?primary</item>
   <item name="colorOnSecondary">?onPrimaryH</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/HintText</item>
</style>

 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/core_text"
        style="@style/TextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:theme="@style/TextInputLayout"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:hint="Trip name" />
 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Also if you need to change box stroke, you need to the override default color

```
<color name="colorTextInputStroke">#CCD1D3</color>
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">
        @color/colorTextInputStroke
</color>
```

Comment: you not use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText widget, why?

Comment: It's just an example where you need to use this style. So full code will be like as your code but with this changes
style="@style/TextInputLayout"
android:theme="@style/TextInputLayout"

Comment: check please this
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/colors.xml
and this  https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/styles.xml
You need to override some colors

Comment: i try override colors but unsuccesfull, i try this demos and colors on it is because primary and secondary color, no because override it.. i havent result of my problem :(